# Is it necessary to create index for column which only contains 7 or 8 possible strings?

Tags: mysql, database

And what about more or less possible strings that may store in that column?

Answer (score 0):

The key point is not the number of distinct *values*, it is the number of *rows* that the query engine has to take into account (worst case, using a table scan) when optimising your query. So yes, if your table has a non-negligible number of rows, you should create your index.